# How can I force/setup the right keyboard in the iOS Simulator during tests?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, ios-simulator, xcode-scheme

The app has a Chinese localization and runs with Scheme options (see image).

When I hit the text field, I would expect a Chinese keyboard and not a German one.
I only see German, English and Emoji keyboards.

Is there any way to tell the Simulator which keyboard should be used by default?

[image: Scheme options and Simulator screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not automatic. You should manually add a Chinese keyboard and make it the default.

Navigate to **Settings/Keyboards**, add the Chinese keyboard under **Keyboards** and drag it to the first place of the list after clicking on **Edit**.

[image: Settings/Keyboards/Keyboards]

Comment: It did not work in my test environment. I still hope someone knows an automatic solution.